# I want my RecyclerView to not recycle some items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm using a `RecyclerView` with heterogeneous views inside, [as seen in this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView).

I have some items inside that RecyclerView that are RecyclerViews too. Too hard to imagine? Let's say I want to copy the Play Store's layout: One big RecyclerView with vertical linear layout and filled by many elements: Single apps and carousel of apps.

If the item to add is the layout for a single app then ID 1 will be used and I will add the layout for a single item.
Else, if I need to add a Carousel then I will add one element to the main RecyclerView: Another RecyclerView with its own adapter.

That works very well. Except when you scroll the main RecyclerView. Why? Because some views are being destroyed when no more visible and then recreated in the `onBindViewHolder()` method. Why here? Because the Adapter of the main RecyclerView is passing for the position X and then calls `OnBindViewHolder()`. The latter then creates a new RecyclerView with its own adapter and assigns it to it. I'd like to keep those views just because they are heavy to reinflate every time.

Is this possible? If so, can you tell me how?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use this:

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(TYPE_CAROUSEL, 0);
```

This will not recycle any view of viewType `TYPE_CAROUSEL` but if the item count of this type is very high, then it will reduce your performance significantly, maybe even cause OOMEs

And if you adapter only have one type of view and therefore you do not override the `getItemViewType(position: Int): Int` method, you can pass 0 as the firts parameter of the `setMaxRecycledViews` function.

**EDIT**

After reading *MML13*'s answer, I think it might work for you. You are worried about items of your carousel being reinflated when that view is rebinded in outer RecyclerView. If all those carousel's are of same type, i.e., they all use same adapter, you can keep the adapter inside outer RecyclerView's ViewHolder, and just swap out data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemRangeChanged(...)` on this adapter when it's rebinded. This will recycle all carousel views and all views inside those carousels.

Comment: what is the default value to be passed for `int viewType` parameter?? i couldnt find any documentation for it?

Comment: @Sanoop Unless you Override `getItemViewType`, the default viewType is `0` (see [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#5818))

Comment: how do you go about declaring TYPE_CAROUSEL in the adapter? do you have any examples of initialization and assignment etc

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Comment: Note: TYPE_CAROUSEL can be any integer 

   " private static final int TYPE_CAROUSEL = 1;"

is declared at the top of my adapter

Then I override getItemViewType and only return TYPE_CAROUSEL under a certain condition and i return 0 for all other conditions.

Thanks for the help @Sourabh!!

Answer (score 65):

You can also set below code in your onBindViewholder() method of adapter.

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

I have taken reference from this link

http://aphoe.com/blog/prevent-androids-recyclerview-recycling-views/

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!! That saved me from a huge headache! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: That link you provided is dead

Comment: This stops it from being recycled, but it doesn't even reuse it for the item that was bound when it was set to false.  If ItemA is set to recyclable false, then scrolled away and gone back to, ItemA gets a new view, it's old view that was set to false is just taken out of circulation.  How can the recycler be told to use that specific view when it comes back to itemA?

Answer (score 10):

> Because some views are being destroyed when no more visible and then
>   recreated in the onBindViewHolder() method.

It is not true, they are not created again, they just rebind. if you have a view for position X (in scrap or recycler) `RecyclerView` is going to use that and rebind it.

> I'd like to keep those views just because they are heavy to reinflate every time.

The main `RecyclerView` keeps those for you. You only need to change the adapter data of your second `RecyclerView` and call `notifyDataSetChanged`. Also store your second `RecyclerView` adapter inside the `viewHolder` of your main `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 6):

Set the below line in your activity

`recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(1,0);`

set Below Code in RecyclerViewAdapter class

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My code is working for reset UI in recycleview.

```
public class BooleanViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<ConfigItemBoolean> {
    private SwitchCompat configBoolean;

    BooleanViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        configBoolean = view.findViewById(R.id.enable_config_boolean);
        configBoolean.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            ((ConfigItemBoolean) getItem(getAdapterPosition())).setValue(isChecked);
            DataSet.mConfigDataSet.getConfigItemBooleanMap().put(configPairList.get(getAdapterPosition()).first, ((ConfigItemBoolean) getItem(getAdapterPosition())));
        });
    }

    @Override
    void bind(ConfigItemBoolean item, String key) {
        configBoolean.setText(item.getDisplayName());
        configBoolean.setChecked(item.isValue());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(youViewHolder type,0);
```

if you use
viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);  will ocur multi same viewholder in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

The only solution worked for me was:

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(INT)
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)
```

In that case RecyclerView items will not be recycled, but can be replaced or deleted.