# Prevent RecyclerView from recycling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

I'm using `FlexboxLayoutManager` in `RecyclerView` and I need to prevent RV from recycling. I tried to set `itemViewCacheSize()` to total items count, but it didn't help. Also I tried to set `maxedRecycledViews()` to 0 with no result. How can I prevent RV from recycling?

Comment: "I need to prevent RV from recycling" -- then do not use `RecyclerView`. Why would you want to use `RecyclerView` without recycling views? Perhaps there is some other solution to whatever problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need `RecyclerView` for it's drag and drop feature. In plane `FlexboxLayout` drag and drop doesn't work like in `RecyclerView`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want my RecyclerView to don't recycle some items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313079/i-want-my-recyclerview-to-dont-recycle-some-items)

Comment: `RecyclerView` does not have a drag-and-drop feature AFAIK. Drag-and-drop can be implemented using a `RecyclerView`, but that's not built in. If `FlexboxLayout` is preventing you from implementing drag-and-drop in a `RecyclerView`, file a bug with the flexbox project, or do not use `FlexboxLayout`. Using `RecyclerView` properly, including recycling views, is **much** more important than is using `FlexboxLayout`, IMHO.

Comment: @CommonsWare in my project i need to build grid of `TextureViews` with videos in it. Also i need to change grid configuration (which include resizing) without reloading videos. I can achieve than by setting `LayoutParams` to each child of `RecyclerView` or `FlexboxLayout` without `RecyclerView`. But when i'm scrolling my items in `RecyclerView`, videos are starting to reload. That's why i need either increase recycle pool of prevent `RecyclerView` from recycling at all

Answer (score 4):

Call setIsRecyclable(false) under onBindViewHolder.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ManşetViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
}
```