# Is there a way not to recycle only the first item in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-videoview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using a recyclerview for my list of items. The first item has a video streaming from my camera, as soon as I scroll past the list of items, the first item gets recycled aka disrupts the streaming video until I get back to it. Is there a way I can prevent it from recycling and making sure my camera captures my video at all times without any disruption whether I scroll or not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could use this on the recyclerView to prevent it from recycling views of the specified viewType.

`recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(VIEW_TYPE, 0);`

[Check out this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313079/i-want-my-recyclerview-to-not-recycle-some-items)

Comment: how do i set the VIEW_TYPE?