# Lottie Animation canceling automatically in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, lottie

I'm using lottie animation inside my recyclerView.Here is a my source

```
     if (story.isRead)
            lottieAnimationView.setAnimation("story_archive_gray.json");
        else
            lottieAnimationView.setAnimation("story_archive_blue.json");



        final LinearLayout loadMoreContainer = v.findViewById(R.id.load_more_container);
        loadMoreContainer.setVisibility(story.isLastElement ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        rootView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            lottieAnimationView.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    SPLogger.logMassage("animationListener","onAnimationEnd");
                    animation.cancel();
                    //call activity
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    SPLogger.logMassage("animationListener","onAnimationCancel");

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                    SPLogger.logMassage("animationListener","onAnimationRepeat");



                }
            });
            lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();

        });
```

I have one problem, sometimes animation does not finishing and onAnimationCancel has calling automatically .can anyone tell me a reason?
I put my json files inside asset folders

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want my RecyclerView to not recycle some items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313079/i-want-my-recyclerview-to-not-recycle-some-items)

Comment: ^ not an exact duplicate, but this appears to be likely the cause for the cancellation.

Comment: I'm using custom view, not recyclerView @Martin Zeitler

Comment: do you have any experience in Lottie ?

Comment: I have, that's why I think that something higher up in the view-hierarchy might interfere and cause the animation to cancel. you could set a break-point within `onAnimationCancel()` and then check the call-stack, if one can see the origin.

Comment: I can share my xml code,if you want @Martin Zeitler

Comment: this might make question more clear, because you refer to a `RecyclerView` ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191485/discussion-between-bekakk-and-martin-zeitler).

Comment: better try to set a break-point, to find out what is going on... I'm cooking right now.

Comment: I tried it and As I said cancel method called @Martin Zeitler

Comment: it doesn't matter that it is being called, but what calls it. the call-stack is just alike a stack-trace, just not crashed with an exception... it only gets tricky when there are several threads involved.

Comment: can you share a solution ? I did not understand your response correctly  @Martin Zeitler

Comment: see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNKM4GLBpDg) or this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBaL78HC0ls)... the window bottom-left is what I'm taking about. such issues don't have a default solution. one has to identify the actual problem, else one has little chance... things don't "just happen" (unless the OS is low on RAM).

Comment: Dear Martin,I know how to use breakpoint in Android studio,but in this case I can't check a reason @Martin Zeitler

Comment: as stated [low ram](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/low-ram) can have an effect on animations... there also is a profiler for RAM & GPU. also seen the [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/1175) on GitHub, but they'll most likely also will label it "needs more information".

Comment: It's my github issue  :))))