# How to disable recyclerview scroll to top (1st item) on notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have fixed number of items in recycler view, but I update data every 10 seconds and calling notifyDataSetChanged();

When I scrolled to Nth item (EX:20th item) and on notifyDataSetChanged() called recycler view getting refreshed and auto-scroll back to 1st item. How can I stop scrolling and update the recycler view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have any special index... I have a fixed number of items. Do I need to use the maximum index?

Comment: Most of us do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` once list object is update. You can also try by creating a method to in `RecyclerAdapter` class which will update the list object of adapter class and then just calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` within it.

Comment: provide some code, to understand how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `view type` and holder for your first item then set `setIsRecyclable`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder ) {
        ((HeaderViewHolder ) holder).setIsRecyclable(false);
        ((HeaderViewHolder ) holder).bind(mData.get(position));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is HeaderViewHolder here?

Comment: It is a normal `ViewHolder`. You should use two different `ViewHolder`. One is for header and the other is for normal items. Then disable `recycle` for your header type. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313079/i-want-my-recyclerview-to-not-recycle-some-items)

Answer (score 0):

Using `onSaveInstanceState` you will save the state or current position of your `recyclerview`.Just like this.

Create variable in your activity

```
Parcelable recylerViewList; //this will store the position
```

then create this method to fetch `recyclerview` state

```
void storeInstance() {
    AttachmentsActivity.recylerViewList=mRecyclerView?.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
}// call this method before notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Create method to restore the state

```
    void restore() //call this method after notifyDataSetChanged()
    {
     mRecyclerView?.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(recylerViewList)
    }
```

Make sure you call this `methods` in `activity` or through `activity object`.

Answer (score 0):

You should find which items changed and use `adapter.notifyItemChanged(itemChangedPosition)` instead of `notifyDatasetChanged()`