# How to prevent updating items that are loaded before in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which contains two view types. for one view type I want to prevent recyclerview from updating that item as it is loaded before and is costly.
I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36313437/13083841) and I think its not related to my question.
is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I finally had to cache all views by this line:

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(adapter.getItemCount())
```

but this may lead to bad performance.