# LazyColumn to not recompose some items

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

With `RecyclerView`, I can make some `ViewHolder` not recyclable (follow some answers in
[I want my RecyclerView to not recycle some items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36313079/5381331)).
Can I make `LazyColumn` to not recompose some items (similar to make `RecyclerView` don't recycle some `ViewHolder`)? I have few items in `LazyColumn` with some big images, it recompose after scrolling down and up so scroll is not smooth.

Comment: it doesn't recompose unless you've done something wrong. Check out [this example](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/63317e2f3a2572226171f5c9a544ce99), logs firing only once for each cell when it appears, no recomposition happens during scrolling(expect new appearing cells)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I tried you example but it recompose after I scroll to bottom then scroll up to the top.

Comment: It's a lazy list and for sure it should recompose when the cell disappears and then appears again. While not on then screen the lazy view is removed from the view tree, and needs to be composed when appears again.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov yes, I agree with you but my question is different. `LazyColumn` solve the same problem like `RecyclerView`. You can check again this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313079/i-want-my-recyclerview-to-not-recycle-some-items. In some case, we still want to make some item in RecyclerView to not recycle (eg: the item contains large image, canvas, or video). RecyclerView support this and I'm migrate from RecyclerView to LazyColumn

Comment: I get it now, didn't notice that link, my bad. As far as I know, there is no way to do this with `LazyColumn`, I suggest you [create a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128).

Comment: Is there no answer for this?  I am having the same issue.  I am displaying some items, which my app fetches remotely, in a lazy column.  One of those items is an HTML string.  So I am using WebView to display it.  Unfortunately, the WebView gets recomposed every time it goes in/out of screen, causing some flickering.  So, I want just the WebView item to not recompose.  As mentioned by OP, this is possible in RecyclerView.  But I can't find any solution for LazyColumn.

Comment: I was able to solve my WebView-in-LazyColumn issue.  I just pre-created the WebView instance and returned the same instance in AndroidView.  This way, even when AndroidView gets recomposed, WebView does not get recreated and only 1 instance gets used in every recomposition.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and use Column instead with a modifier vertical scroll. If you don't want it recycle view, just load all ( few items)

```
Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(listView) {
                    top.linkTo(
                        parent.top
                    )
                }
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            list.forEachIndexed { index, itemModel ->
               ItemView(itemModel, index) {
                    // on item click
                }
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))
        }
```

Comment: Use `Column` instead of `LazyColumn` could help. Unfortunately, I need `LazyColumn` to support drag and drop item in list so I can not use `Column`

Comment: [link](https://github.com/aclassen/ComposeReorderable)  did u try this one?

Comment: yes, currently I'm using this library to support drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a composable that is heavily manipulating bitmaps and then draw them on a canvas. You noticed that processing while scrolling the lazyColumn up and down.

To face this issue a stored my manipulated bitmaps in a `List<ImageBitmap>` as `rememberSaveable`

```kotlin
val rememberFruits by rememberSaveable(images) {         
    mutableStateOf(doBitmapOperations(images))
}

Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(height)
        .constrainAs(circle) {}
) {
    rememberFruits
        .forEach { createScaledImageBitmap ->
            val (image, offset) = createScaledImageBitmap
            drawImage(
                image = image,
                topLeft = offset
            )
        }
}
```

My item in the lazyColumn was still recomposed but the heavy bitmap operations were no more executed while scrolling and making scrolling up and down smooth.

hope it helps!